# Passing login information through a URL to a form with changing attribute names

Tags: html, forms, url, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am working on a project which involves setting up a bunch of dashboards around the office. The plan is to use Screenly on Raspberry Pi 3s, as it seems to fit our needs for the most part at a very low cost. The problem is, some of the webpages that need to be displayed are locked behind a login. Screenly doesn't have a way to get past this, other than passing the login information and the page redirect through the URL itself. I am aware of the potential security issues this could bring, which is why the account we crated for this use can only view (and not edit) very specific pages.

I want to pass login information through a URL in order to login to a website and directly access a specific page on that website. I have had success passing login information in the form of:

```
https://website.com/dologin.action?username=CapnCrunch&password=Fr00tl00ps&login=Log+in&os_destination=%2Fpages%2Fviewpage.action%3FpageId%58008
```

This works nicely when the username and password attribute names are always the same, but not when they change on every refresh. Instead of the HTML attributes for the username box remaining the same every time the login page is accessed, they change slightly every time.

For example, these are the HTML attributes for the username upon loading the page for the first time:

```
<input name="ct100$phUser$txtUser8193" type"text" id="txtUser8193"
class="login_user border-box" placeholder="My Username">
```

But when I refresh the page, this same bit of HTML code changes to:

```
<input name="ct100$phUser$txtUser5516" type"text" id="txtUser5516"
class="login_user border-box" placeholder="My Username">
```

I would love to pass the URL arguments in the form of:

```
dologin.action?ct100$phUser$txtUserXxXx=CapnCrunch
```

Where XxXx is just whatever number the page decided to use at that time.

All the solutions I have found online include using external scripts of some kind. The problem is, Screenly only accepts URLs. Using a script would involve either editing Screenly's source code, or using a proxy webpage.

Is there any way to get around the changing attribute name without using external scripts?

Thanks in advance